NX Build Fails After Upgrading Prettier and using in an app a Webpack-Obfuscator Plugin
I'm working on an Angular project using Nx and have set up a custom Webpack plugin that includes webpack-obfuscator for code obfuscation. Everything was working fine until I upgraded the prettier package (3.3.3). I haven't run Prettier yet, just upgraded it. Now, when I try to build the app using Nx, the build fails with the following error:
NX ERROR at line 222: Unexpected token (222:18)
HookWebpackError: ERROR at line 222: Unexpected token (222:18)
    ...
Error: ERROR at line 222: Unexpected token (222:18)
    at Function.processParsingError (webpack://javascript-obfuscator/./src/ASTParserFacade.ts:77:15)
    ...

It seems to be related to the WebpackObfuscator plugin, as removing the custom Webpack plugin resolves the issue. The error suggests a problem with handling a Promise during the obfuscation process.
Has anyone encountered this issue or have any idea why upgrading Prettier might cause this problem?
Thanks
Plugin Code:
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
const WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');

const webpackConfig = (config: webpack.Configuration): webpack.Configuration => {
  config.plugins!.push(
    new WebpackObfuscator({
        compact: true,
        stringArray: true,
        stringArrayThreshold: 0.8,
        splitStrings: true,
        splitStringsChunkLength: 10,
        rotateStringArray: true,
        selfDefending: true,
        shuffleStringArray: true,
        target: 'browser-no-eval'
     }, ['polyfills*', 'vendor*', 'loader*'])
  );
  return config;
};

export default webpackConfig;


now I know what happened:
The API changed for the prettier.format() method. Now it returns a Promise instead of a string. We need to handle that in our custom plugins.
